# Elastic Beanstalk with development and production environment?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I made a Django project and have successfully deployed it to an Elastic Beanstalk environment, let's say it's called **app_name**. However, I realized I needed 2 environments: **development** and **production**. The purpose of this is so I can try things out in **development**, and when I know it's fully working, I can deploy it in **production** for the public to use.

I tried looking around their documentations and found [Managing multiple Elastic Beanstalk environments as a group with the EB CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebcli-compose.html) . It basically says you can create a group of environments in one project with the command:

```
~/workspace/project-name$ eb create --modules component-a component-b --env-group-suffix group-name
```

However, I'm not sure what a group means. I mean, I just need a **development** and **production** environment.

I'm fairly new at this. How do I create and manage **development** and **production** environments for this purpose? I would ever be so grateful if someone were to shed some light to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running a group of environments is more for different services doing different things. You would have an environment that handles Service One, and an environment that handles Service Two etc. This isn't really what you want.

You just need an environment in the same `application` as your production environment. It doesn't *have* to be in the same application but I like it that way because its useful for deploying an app version to dev, and then deploy the app version to prod once it's tested.

An easy way to do this is run
`eb clone app_name` (where app_name is the name of your production environment)

This will clone your production environment and prompt you to give it a name, which you might set to app_name_dev. From there you can edit your dev environment to make it more suitable for dev (maybe you'd make the instances smaller, change software variables like MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun to MAIL_DRIVER=mailtrap, connect it to a dev database instead of your prod database, etc)

**The downside** of doing this would be if your production environment is currently running jobs or doing anything meaningful, you may not want to clone it right away since the new dev environment could start doing these things too, before you manage to update its config to point to a dev DB etc! If this is the case, you would just run `eb create my_app_dev` and configure it from scratch.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer. So, to summarize what you explained: create two similar environments (development and production) in the same app, both referring to the same project repository?

Comment: @adrilz exactly. The two similar environments (development and production) will not be linked to each other, so they can be running different versions of your code even if they are referring to the same repository.

Comment: The two environments may not be linked to each other, but they refer to the same project. I know you can have two versions of a project by using different branches (let's say development and master branch), but settings like database names will be the same once you merge development branch to master branch. Of course you can choose which parts to merge, but I feel that's rather not efficient. How do you handle this?

Comment: Nvm, I think I've figured it out. I just realized branches didn't work the way I said before. I can keep 2 versions without choosing which part to merge each time. Thank you, Eden. Sorry I asked too many questions.